# Authenticate jquery-mobile app with json backend (making API)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

For my php-web-app I use ajax calls to populate content.

Username and token is stored in cookie, and on every page view this cookie is read, compared to DB, and object $user is created.

Later in my php functions, I use this object to see who is viewing specific page and display relevant data.

Now I'd like to extend my php functions to accept calls from remote mobile-apps and display data for specific (authenticated user).

My question is how to authenticate mobile-app with php based json API? How to actually make this API authentication?

Possible solution I was thinking is to append to request url username and token and use that to do same as I do with cookie data.

What is the common way of doing this process?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign each user an API key and use that instead of passing credentials in the querystring:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    headers: {
        'X-API-KEY':'MYKEY'
    }})
```

Comment: Can I pass user/pass via headers too? What is benefit of using API key? I already use tokens on the website, instead of saving pass in cookie on client side, I simply create token every time user logins and use that. I imagine it can be as API key also.

Comment: Right, then just use the token. You should not be passing username and password around in headers. Also, and I probably don't need to tell you this, but you MUST use HTTPS if you're going to use this token approach.